# Game Center - no achievement

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, center

Today my app was accept by apple and now is on AppStore. 
App has game center (leaderboard and achievements"
but, when somebody download this app from appstore has:
"No Achievements" or "Unable to Load Achievements"
and nothing in leaderboard.
Before i upload app to AppStore, achievements and leaderboard was enable with sandbox.
On iTunes Connect i have my leaderboards and achievemnts.
How can fix it?

Comment: can you screenshot the screen?  Is it the default achievements window that is showing both errors you listed?

Comment: http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/313/pictureuf.png <- here is screen from game center. I check in Game Center App and when my friend played in this game i Game Center App was "XX YY played "Title of game" 1 hours ago"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a networking issue?  When you are testing it, do you have wifi connected, or are you using 3g?   It is possible that you just can not connect to the internet.

Try opening safari, and see if you can browse the web?

Also make sure you are logged in to game center sandbox.  When your app loads, do you see "Your user name"/welcome to game center?

A link to help out.
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/59551-GameCenter-Plugin-Live!-Leaderboards-and-Achievements!/page55